# What does "in various forms" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> We will use your certain video to **promote the advertiser’s product or
>   service in various forms.**

Does the bold part mean "promote the advertiser’s (product or service in various forms)" or "promote the advertiser's (product or service) using various ways"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the latter. Basically it says that your video will be used however the organization you're making an agreement with wants to use the video.

Your video will be used will be used in "various forms" to promote the advertiser's product or service. Those various forms could be, for instance, a commercial on TV, a video billboard, or a video ad on Facebook. Perhaps the audio track could be used in a radio ad.